# Excel ListObject and Control - detaching the Control

Tags: vb.net, excel, controls, listobject

So I have created a ListObject in Excel at runtime:

```
list = ws.Controls.AddListObject(somerange,"somename")
```

Now I have a ListObject and a Control on the sheet: ws.ListObjects.Count = 1 and ws.Controls.Count = 1. How do i "detach" the Control from the ListObject so when using

```
ws.Controls.RemoveAt(0)
```

deletes only the control and not the ListObject itself?

Saving the file and re-opening it does this - it leaves only the ListObject on the page, the Control is gone. But how to do it at runtime?

Comment: Try turning on the macro recorder and adding the `ListObject`. That will give you the correct syntax.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is in VB.NET, not VBA and I need the Control initially to manipulate the `ListObject` - populating with data from a `DataTable`. Just in need to get rid of it later as it does some weird stuff (`SheetChange` event firing twice) without deleting the `ListObject` itself.

Comment: KimI think you can still do ws.Listobjects.Add though. But I can't test it now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the thing. As per the above code, at the end of the procedure you must get rid of the `list` variable. I thought the garbage collector would do this but probably I was wrong. The `list.Dispose()` at the end of the sub does the trick and although the `Control` is still there, there is no more weird stuff going on.